# How to secure an APK file to protect it from decompilation

Tags: android, proguard, apk

I have an Android project, and I want to protect the APK file because I found it very easy to decompile. With a little research, I found ProGuard, but I don't know how to use it to protect my app.

Answer (score 3):

how about trying ProGuard yourself? a really good explanation could be found over here: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/index.html

Comment: Thanks but i dident understand it very well, i need a sample tutorial that shows how to use proguard to obfuscate my android application.

Comment: ProGuard is a good start to make the apk safer but it is NOT the final solution, especially in areas like fintech, healthcare, etc. A very detailed explanation of the reason can be found in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50771792/4092588)

Answer (score 1):

- I use [quixxi](https://quixxi.com/), it is much simpler and more efficient than Proguard.
- You can also try [whitecryption](https://www.intertrust.com/products/application-security/), have no experience with it though.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you don't protect the file against decompilation but you simply make it harder to understand your decompiled code/logic

1. the first tool you can use to immediately increase the difficulty in reading the decompiled code is ProGuard, which you can [activate directly](https://medium.com/@maheshwar.ligade/enabling-proguard-for-android-98e2b19e90a4) in Android Studio
2. ProGuard provides obfuscation for free and is super nice but not necessarily enough to guarantee the right level of security. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50771792/4092588) to understand the practical difference in the code readability of the sample code [original code, code after proguard only and code after professional tool]
3. some other good tips are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39990443/8866430). In particular if the level of security required is very tight [fintech, healthcare, etc.] I strongly suggest you to consider paid solutions like DexGuard, Quixxi, Arxan just to say a few. The advantage with them is that they can automate most of the best practices, leaving you only with the duty to take care about functionalities [i.e. without thinking about security practices]. Which means faster and safer delivery